# ¿Como puedo hacer para que mi programa solo permita colocar numeros y que me indique si el jtextfield esta vacio?

Tags: jframe, combobox

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo una calculadora basica en un jframe utilizando el combobox, pero necesito que, si el usuario coloca una letra el programa le diga que no esta permitido usar letras, tambien que si el campo esta vacio, que el programa le diga que el campo este vacio.

Comment: Bienvenidx a Stack Overflow en español. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Answer (score 1):

usanso los keysListener

micampo.addKeyListener(new KeysListener(){
//aqui van implementados los metodos como el
keyPressed, keyReleased, keyType
})

con esto cada vez que se escriba un carácter en el campo de texto se ejecutaran eso eventos que a su vez tendrán tu código que es lo que quieras que hagas. y lo combinas con el método matches algo asi. y así podrás saber si es letra o numero if(cmp_materno.getText().matches("aquí tu expresión regular (/[0-9]+)")){no es un carácter} algo a si

espero y te sirva de guía